# Passing variable from jade to ng-init not working

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug, angularjs-ng-init

I'm trying to pass an object from jade to ng-init in angular

This: doesn't work:

```
ng-init='tables=!{JSON.stringify(tables)}'
```

This: expands but,

```
ng-init='tables=#{JSON.stringify(tables)}'
```

the output is unescaped and filled with `&quot;`s

```
ng-init="tables={&quot;12&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:....
```

and the view isn't updated in either of the cases. [This article](http://www.mircozeiss.com/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-from-a-server-to-angular) implies that first one should work, but like I said, it doesn't even expand,

```
ng-init='tables=!{JSON.stringify(tables)}'
```

in source code shows up exactly the same in the HTML source

```
ng-init='tables=!{JSON.stringify(tables)}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the `#{...}` approach seems to work fine.
It is probably the way `console.log` prints attributes' values that confused you.

```
ng-init="tables=#{JSON.stringify(tables)}"
```

Take a look at this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WE37T1VgA1f76GhB0vXg?p=preview)**.

Comment: In a custom directive, `ng-init` is not executed in the `controller` but in the `link` function. I ran into this again today and I was trying to access ng-init-ed variables from the controller instead of the link.

Answer (score -1):

In what use-case you want to pass data directly from Jade to angular? I think you could to this job in controller like this :

> $scope.init = function () {
>      // init stuff
>   }

...and in your view :

> ng-init = init()

Comment: This won't work. Angular cannot access server-side variables

Comment: Sure, if you do something like this `ng-init = init({{ my_backend_var }})`

Comment: Ah okay, I was referring to the fact that you cannot set it inside the controller.